# Spring JPA Pageable Repository DataType Mismatch

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring based application which uses JPA for handling data base related procedures. I'm using pagination to improve the application performance, how ever I've been facing a very particular issue regarding the data type returned by the repository method. I need my repositories to return a `List` of elements, I'm passing a `Pageable` object to the repository method to get only the records I need according to page parameters, according to this docs http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html I should be able to get the `List` of elements I want by simply replacing the return data type of the reposiroty method from `Page<User>` to `List<User>`, but for some reason it works only for some methods but not for all of them, for example, my `findAll` method for this entity class should be returning a `List<User>` but instead is returning a `Page<User>`, but if I turn this same method into a custom `@Query` method (`SELECT t FROM Table t`), then I get the `List<User>` as expected. I'm not sure which are the  conditions for this unexpected bahaviour to happen since I've implemented other repository methods using `Pageable` and those are working as expected, returning a `List<>` instead of a `Page<>`.
 I'm not even sure how is this working and my HTTP controller is allowing to return the `Page<User>` even tough is set to return a `List<User>`.

Why is this happening and how can I avoid this behaviour? Is there a way to force Spring to return the data type declared on a method signature for these cases?

Here's the repository significant code:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

    public List<User> findAll();

    //This way the method is returning a Page<> object
    public List<User> findAll(Pageable pageable);

    ....
    ...
}
```

using `@Query`

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

    public List<User> findAll();

    //This way the method is returning a List<User>
    @Query("SELECT t FROM User t")
    public List<User> findAll(Pageable pageable);

    ....
    ...
}
```

I am able to overload `findAll()` method to use the `Pageable` object and it works fine besides of the return type issue.

Comment: `findAll` is declared already by Spring Data itself, you cannot override/change it. If you want to implement page, it is probably better to return a `Page` instead of a `List`. The `Page` also contains information on the number of pages, page size etc. that information is needed on the client to render a table.

Comment: Can you add the code as well ? Our code speaks lot clearer

Comment: @M. Deinum I'm actually able to overload the `findAll()` method to include the `Pageable` object, as well as any other named method from Spring, I've used this approach with many other named methods, in my case I just need the array of data, no need any of the `Page` data since I'm handling this details in front-end....

@javaguy I've updated the question with the piece of code. Thanks

Comment: [`findAll(Pageable)`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java#L371) is already defined by Spring Data. So you aren't overriding anything. You aren't overriding it because that simply isn't possible (unless you are providing your own implementation of that method in your own repository.

Comment: @M. Deinum I never said I'm overriding the method, I said I'm **overloading** the method, there's a big difference beetwen **override** and **overload**. `findAll(Pageable)` is an overloaded implementation of `findAll()` provided by Spring of course

Comment: Agree. But you cannot overload it. You cannot overload a method solely on a return type... And no it isn't overloaded it is overriden as spring data already provides the `findAll(Pageable)` method by default (see the link I provided).